# Carrying variables into new command prompt windows

Tags: batch-file

I want a batch file that opens and:

1. Sets all items in list.txt to variable v one at a time.
2. For each of the items in list.txt to open a command prompt and run starter.bat
3. Carry variable v into starter.bat

My code

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%v in (C:\users\anhall\desktop\test\list.txt) DO START c:\users\anhall\desktop\test\starter.bat
ENDLOCAL & SET computer=%v%
```

this is just an example of what will be in there, when I get it all figured out there should be a couple hundred items in the list.  But I will probably break it down into smaller lists for ease of running.

list.txt

nhn-0073
nhn-0115
nhn-0846

This is what I end up with on the primary window:

[image: Beginning loop.bat problem.png]

I can see that its not working because it doesn't even carry to `ENDLOCAL & SET computer=`

My main concern is carrying the variable into each of the new windows.  I know this is possible but I can't get it to work.

### Completed Code

My code

```
SETLOCAL
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%v in (C:\users\anhall\desktop\test\list.txt) DO START c:\users\anhall\desktop\test\starter.bat %%v
```

changes to starter.bat

```
changed variable to %1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass it in on the command line:

```
for /F %%v in (YourFile.txt) do start c:\users\anhall\desktop\test\starter.bat %%v
```

Modify your `starter.bat` file to use `%1` to receive the variable from the command line.

```
:: Starter.bat - replace echo with your actual command
@echo %1
```

(Doing it from the command line means you never change the `computer` environmental variable, so you can remove the `& SET` at the end of your first batch file.)